# If $f$ is continuous and bounded, and $\text{span}\{x \mapsto f(x+k) \mid k \in \Bbb Z\}$ is finite-dimensional, what can we say about $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

> If $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous and bounded, and $\text{span}\{x \mapsto f(x+k) \mid k \in \Bbb Z\}$ is finite-dimensional, what can we say about $f$?

I found this problem difficult (I found examples of functions for which the hypothesis is true like $n$-periodic functions, where $n \in \Bbb N^*$, but I am struggling for the reverse implication). Can someone help me solve it and does someone have a reference from where it comes?

Comment: Can you come up with some examples of such $f$, and some non-examples? What do the examples have in common?

Comment: Maybe the function would be periodic with a natural period. Just a guess

Comment: @Ramanujan I updated the post.

Comment: Just thought/question, but if $K$ is a nilpotent operator and we define $f(x) = \lVert K^x \rVert$, where $\lVert \cdot\rVert$ is the operator norm,  wouldn't that imply that the span is finite-dimensional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim.** *If is $f$ is continuous and bounded, then $\,\mathrm{span}\,\{f(x+k): k\in\mathbb Z\}\,$ is a finite dimensional space if and only if $f$ is of the form
$$
f(x)= \exp\big(i\varphi_1 x\big)e_1(x)+\cdots+
\exp\big(i\varphi_k x\big)e_k(x), \tag{$\star$}
$$
where $e_1,\ldots,e_k$ are continuous $1-$periodic functions and $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_k\in [0,2\pi)$, distinct.*

The inverse is straight-forward since if we assume that $f$ is of the form $(\star)$, then $f(x),f(x+1),\ldots,f(x+k)$ are linearly dependent.

First, let's study the discrete problem:

If a vector $(a_j)_{j\in\mathbb Z}$ satisfies the recursive relation
$$
a_{j+n}+c_{n-1}a_{j+n-1}+c_{n-2}a_{j+n-2}+\cdots+c_{0}a_{j}=0, \quad j\in\mathbb Z, \tag{1}
$$
where $c_0,\ldots,c_{n-1}$ are given constants (complex in general), then $(a_j)_{j\in\mathbb Z}$ is uniquely expressed in the form
$$
a_j=p_1(j)w_1^j+\cdots+p_k(j)w_k^j,\quad j\in\mathbb Z,
$$
where $w_1,\ldots,w_k$ are the distinct roots of the polynomial
$$
P(x)=x^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+c_1x+c_0,
$$
and $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ are polynomials with $\,\deg p_\ell<$ multiplicity of the root $w_\ell$ in the polynomial $P(x)$. If $|w_\ell|>1$ or $0<|w_\ell|<1$, for
some $\ell=1,\ldots,k$, then $(a_j)_{j\in\mathbb Z}$ would not be bounded. Also, if $|w_\ell|=1$ and $\,\deg p_\ell\ge 1$, then again $(a_j)_{j\in\mathbb Z}$
would not be bounded.

Hence, a vector $(a_j)_{j\in\mathbb Z}$ satisfying $(1)$
is bounded if and only if it is of the form
$$
a_j=d_1w_1^j+\cdots+d_k w_k^j,\quad j\in\mathbb Z,
$$
where $d_1,\ldots,d_k$ constants and $|w_1|=\cdots=|w_k|=1$ and of course, the $w_\ell$'s are still distinct roots of $P(x)$.

If  $a_j$'s and $c_k$'s are real, then
$(a_j)_{j\in\mathbb Z}$ should be of the form
$$
a_j=\sum_{\ell=1}^k d_\ell\cos (w_\ell j)+e_\ell\sin (w_\ell j), \quad j\in\mathbb Z.
$$

Back to the continuous problem, assume that $f(x)$ is continuous and bounded and satisfies
$$
f(x+n)+c_{n-1}f(x+n-1)+c_{n-2}f(x+n-2)+\cdots+c_{0}f(x)=0, \quad x\in\mathbb R.
$$
Fixing $x\in \mathbb R$, and setting $a_j(x)=f(x+j)$, we obtain, based on our previous discussion, that
$$
a_j(x)=d_1(x)w_1^j+\cdots+d_k(x) w_k^j=f(x+j),\quad j\in\mathbb Z, \tag{2}
$$
where, the $w_\ell$'s are the distinct roots of the polynomial $P(x)$
and $|w_1|=\cdots=|w_k|=1$.
In $(2)$, if we set $j=1,\ldots,k$, we obtain a $k\times k$ linear system with unknowns $d_1(x), \ldots, d_k(x)$. The matrix of the system is $(w_k^j)_{j,k}$, and it is invertible since it is a Vandermonde matrix. Hence the system possesses a unique solution vector $\big(d_1(x),\ldots,d_k(x)\big)$, with is expressed uniquely as a linear combination of the values of $f(x+1),\ldots,f(x+k)$. Hence the $d_\ell$'s are all continuous functions.

So far we have shown that, is $f$ satisfies the conditions of the question, and $a_j(x)=f(x+j)$, then $a_j(x)$ is expressed as in $(2)$, uniquely (once we know $f$ and the unit roots of $P$), with $d_\ell$'s continuous functions and $w_\ell$ discrete unit complex numbers.

Also
$$
d_1(x+1)w_1^{j}+\cdots+d_k(x+1) w_k^{j}=
a_{j}(x+1)=f(x+j+1) \\ =a_{j+1}(x)=d_1(x)w_1^{j+1}+\cdots+d_k(x) w_k^{j+1} \\=
w_1d_1(x)w_1^{j}+\cdots+w_kd_k(x) w_k^{j}
$$
and hence, due to the uniqueness
$$
d_\ell(x+1)=w_\ell d_\ell(x), \quad x\in\mathbb R,\,\,\,\ell=1,\ldots,k.
$$
Clearly, there exist numbers $\varphi_\ell\in [0,2\pi)$, such that $w_\ell=\exp\big(i\varphi_\ell\big)$. Then the functions
$$
e_\ell(x)=\exp\big(-i\varphi_\ell x\big)d_\ell(x), \quad \ell=1,\ldots,k,
$$
are clearly $1-$periodic.

So, we have shown that $f$ is of the form
$$
f(x)=a_0(x)=d_1(x)+\cdots+d_k(x) \\ = \exp\big(i\varphi_1 x\big)e_1(x)+\cdots+
\exp\big(i\varphi_k x\big)e_k(x),
$$
where $e_\ell(x)$ are continuous $1-$periodic functions and $\varphi_\ell$'s distinct numbers in $[0,2\pi)$.

**Note.** If we need to restrict ourselves in $\mathbb R$, then $(\star)$ should be of the form
$$
f(x)=\sum_{\ell=1}^k \big(\cos(\varphi_\ell x)C_\ell(x)+
\sin(\varphi_\ell x)S_\ell(x)\big)
$$
where the $C_\ell$'s and $S_\ell$'s are $1-$periodic functions.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer for the revised question**  Now you translate only by integers.  This is called a "homogeneous linear difference equation with constant coefficients".
$$
0 = \sum_{k=K_1}^{K_2} a_k f(x+k), \quad a_{K_1}\ne 0, a_{K_2}\ne 0
$$
The solution (on the integers) is well-known.  These solutions are functions
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N C_n(x) \;r_n^x
\tag1$$
where $C_n$ are polynomials, and $r_n$ are complex.  Such a solution is bounded (on $\mathbb Z$, positive and negative) only if the polynomials $C_n$ are constants and $|r_n| = 1$.  If we want real values, we get trigonometric expressions for real and imaginary part of $r_n^x$ when $r_n$ is not real.  Such a function need not be periodic, but (if it is bounded) it is a linear combination of periodic functions.  (Allowing irrational periods!)

For solution on $\mathbb R$, take an arbitrary function on a certain "starting interval" $[a,b] = [0,K_2-K_1]$ and extend
(forward and backward) using the difference equation.  So we get something like $(1)$ except that the constant $C_k$ depends on the value in the starting interval.  We choose our function on the starting interval so that it is continuous, and the values at $a$ and $b$ agree to get a solution that is bounded and continuous.

**Previous answer**
This is a nice question.  Many generalizations are possible.
For example, what can you say about a (measurable) function $f$ satisfying $$f(x) -2 f(x+1) + f(x+\sqrt{2}\,) = 0\tag1$$  What happens if you add "continuous" or "bounded" or "$L^p$" to the conditions?  What settings other than $\mathbb R$ can be considered?

**plug**

*Edgar, G. A.; Rosenblatt, J. M.*, [**Difference equations over locally compact Abelian groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1998197), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 253, 273-289 (1979). [ZBL0417.43006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0417.43006).

Comment: Another generalisation: suppose $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth and that the set $\{f_\lambda : x \mapsto f(x-\lambda) ~|~ \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$ generates a finite dimensional vector space. Then $f$ is a solution of a linear ODE with constant coefficients.

Comment: You meant $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N g_n(x)C_n(x) \;r_n^x$ where $C_n$ is a polynomial and $g_n$ is (continuous) $1$-periodic. If $f$ is bounded then $|r_n|=1$ and $C_n(x)$ is constant.

Comment: @reuns  Well, $(1)$ is for the case where the domain is $\mathbb Z$.  In case the domain is $\mathbb R$ are you sure you want period $1$?  Above I used a "starting interval" of length the order of the recurrence.

Comment: If $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb C$ such that $\text{span}\{x \mapsto f(x+k) \mid k \in \Bbb Z\}$ is finite-dimensional, then $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N g_n(x)C_n(x)r_n^x$.

Comment: Simple example:  $f(x) = f(x+2)$, so the span is $2$-dimensional. Write the solution with with $N=1$ and $r_1=1$ and $C_1=1$, so we get merely $f(x) = g_1(x)$.  But your $g_1$ has period $2$, not period $1$.

Comment: My mistake is saying that $g_n $is continuous (when $f$ is). Without it then for $2$-periodic $f$ we have 

$f(x)=\frac{g(x)
}{2|\cos (\pi x)|}(|\cos(\pi x)|+\cos(\pi x))+\frac{h(x)}{2|\cos(\pi x)|}(|\cos(\pi x)|-\cos(\pi x))$ with $g,h$ the $1$-periodization of $f 1_{[0,1)}, f 1_{[1,2)}$, which is of the form I said.

Comment: The $1$-periodic appears because with $F(x)=(f(x),f(x+1),\ldots,f(x+d-1))$ then $F(x+1)=M\ F(x), M\in M_d(\Bbb{C})$.

Comment: Aren't you only using that the shifts $f(\,\cdot\,+k)$ are linearly dependent? Having finite dimensional linear hull seems to be a stronger assumption.

Comment: @Christoph They are the same, $\sum_{n=a}^b c_n f(x+n)=0$ with $c_a\ne 0, c_b\ne 0$ gives that $f(x+b)$ is in the span of $f(x+n),n\in a\ldots b-1$, from which $f(x+b+1)$ is in the span, and so on, and same for $f(x+a-1),f(x+a-2),...$

Comment: @reuns Right, thanks!