# Show that $\exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in ]0,\pi[, \exists n \in \Bbb N, |\sin(xk^n)|\ge \delta$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $k \ge 2$, $k \in \Bbb N$. Show that $\exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in ]0,\pi[, \exists n \in \Bbb N, |\sin(xk^n)|\ge \delta$.

My intuition tells me that we can pick $\delta=1/2$. I tried to study $u_n = \sin(xk^n)=U_{k^n}(\sin(x))=U_k(u_{n-1})$. I thought of introducing a variant of Chebyshev polynomials $U_n(\sin(x))=\sin(nx)$. But it didn't help much. Does someone have a hint? Thanks. (here $\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.)

---

I needed this result for solving this exercice (which is a oral exam that was posed during the competitive exams of Polytechnique, #1 engineering school in France).

> Show that for $f(z)=z^k$ with $k \ge 2$
> $$
> \exists \delta >0, \forall x,y \in \Bbb U, x \neq y \implies \exists n \in \Bbb N, |f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(y)| \ge \delta.
> $$

Suppose $x \neq 0$ and $y/x=e^{i \theta}$,
\begin{align}
| f^{(n)}(x) - f^{(n)}(y) | &= |x^{k^n} - y^{k^n}|
=
 | 1- e^{i \theta k^n}|\\
&= | e^{-i \theta k^n/2} - e^{i \theta k^n/2}|
= |2i \sin(\theta k^n/2)| = 2|\sin (\theta k^n/2)|
\end{align}
So
$$
|f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(y)| \ge \delta \iff |\sin (\theta k^n/2)| \ge \delta/2
$$

Comment: I can prove $\exists\delta \in (0,1), \forall x \in ]0,\pi[, \exists n \in \Bbb N, |\cos(xk^n)|\ge \delta$

Comment: @NN2 ... how do you do that?

Comment: I wrote an answer, with this method, we can prove easily that $\exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in ]0,\pi[, \exists n \in \Bbb N, |\cos(xk^n)|\ge \delta$ by proving $\pi y  \le x k^n\le \pi y + \frac{\pi}{3}$. But it's more difficult for the case $\sin()$

Comment: The claim is of course not true for $x=\frac{\pi*m}{k^{2}}$ and $m<=k^{2}$ so it has to be modified. On the other hand it is true for any sequence with $\sigma <= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ up to a set of measure zero as shown below.

Comment: @Michelle: the claim is still true for the case $x=\pi m/k^2$. Just write x=$\pi (s_1/k+s_2/k^2)$ and take $n=1$. then $\delta=\sin(\pi /k)$. It corresponds to the case 1 of my answer. You have my answer of your problem below.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know where this "square" came from ... . Of course it should be $x = \frac{\pi*m}{k}$ and $m <=k$

Comment: @Salcio: if $x = \frac{\pi m}{k}$ with $1 \le m \le (k-1)$ (of course $m \ne k$) then choose $n = 0$ and you still have $|\sin(xk^0)| \ge \delta = \sin(\pi /k)$.

Comment: Are you saying that $0$ is a natural number?

Comment: @Salcio I'm sorry if my notations weren't clear. I updated the post.

Comment: My proof is long just because I want to make sure it's clear and all ideas should be explicit. The idea is to write $\frac{x}{\pi} = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\frac{s_i}{k^i}$ and prove that $|\sin(xk^n)| \ge \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{k^2} \right)$. You want to have a different solution or rewrite my solution in another way? If the second, I can modify it.

Comment: @NN2 To be clear, the idea in my writeup is the same as yours (though I arrived at it independently). While I haven't read all the details, you surely posted the first correct solution to the problem as asked.

Comment: @NN2 I am very grateful for your solution, I found it very clever! I didn't accept your answer yet because I wanted to wait to see if other approches to this problem are possible (using Chebyshev polynomials or a result about the behavior of $\sin(x)$ I'm not aware of... even if I find this tricky) ;)

Comment: @Michelle Hello Michelle. I think I found a second solution for your problem. You can see my second answer. 
PS: this problem is really interesting. Could you reveal us the motivation, context of it?

Comment: @NN2 Hi! Thanks for your second solution! I edited my post and added some context.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{U},$ is $f(z)=z^k$ just a polynomial, $f^{(n)}$ is the n-derivatives of $f$? I don't know how you connect the two problems. But even if it's an exam of the most selective great schools in France, as the initial problem is still an "oral" exam, it's less probable that you should prove it by using the result of the problem $....|\sin(xk^n)|....$ (unless there exists a third solution simpler than the first two ones). Besides, perhaps when you have the solution of the initial problem, you can write it here and maybe we can find a third solution (which is simpler) from it?

Comment: @NN2 $\Bbb U = \{ z\in \Bbb C \ | \ |z| = 1 \}$. Yes $f$ is a just a polynomial. See the edited post for your other question.

Comment: @NN2 I don't see an other way of tackling this problem and don't be impressed by the difficulty of this (this school is famous for its difficult problems... see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885803/if-f-is-continuous-and-bounded-and-textspan-x-mapsto-fxk-mid-k-in for another good one).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: The OP doesn't say $f^{(n)}$ is the n-th derivative of $f$. From what she wrote, I think $f^{(n)}$ is defined as $f^{(n)}(x)=x^{k^n}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Here $f^{(n)}=f \circ \cdots \circ f$ $n$ times.

Answer (score 6):

I only really see one way to solve this problem, though how you write the details can vary considerably. You asked for an "elegant" solution, so here's my arrangement.

**Key Lemma:** Let $y \in (0, 1)$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}$. Then
$$\{yk^n \pmod{1} : n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\} \cap [1/k^2, 1-1/k^2] \neq \varnothing.$$

**Proof:** Consider the base $k$ expansion of $y$, so $y = 0{.}y_1 y_2 y_3{\ldots}$ and $yk^n \pmod{1} = 0{.}y_{n+1} y_{n+2}{\ldots}$. If the latter expression is not in $[1/k, 1-1/k]$, we must have $y_{n+1} = 0$ or $y_{n+1} = k-1$. So, we may suppose that $y_{n+1} \in \{0, k-1\}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Since $y \neq 0, 1$ by assumption, we have some $N$ where $y_{N+1} \neq y_{N+2}$. Hence $yk^N \pmod{1} = 0{.}y_{N+1} y_{N+2}{\ldots} = 0{.}0(k-1){\ldots}$ or $0{.}(k-1)0{\ldots}$. In the first case, $yk^N \pmod{1} \in [1/k^2, 1/k]$, while in the second case, $yk^N \pmod{1} \in [1-1/k, 1-1/k^2]$. $\Box$

Now set $\delta = \sin(\pi/k^2) > 0$. For all $x \in (0, \pi)$, by the key lemma applied to $y = x/\pi$, we have some $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $xk^n \pmod{\pi} \in [\pi/k^2, \pi-\pi/k^2]$. From the unimodality and symmetry of $\sin$, it follows that $|\sin(xk^n)| \geq |\sin(\pi/k^2)| = \delta$.

Comment: I found a second solution for the problem. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Sure, your second solution basically gives a different proof of a very slight variation on what I called the "key lemma". It has the virtue of working for non-integer values of $k$ and not requiring any discussion of base $k$, perhaps at the cost of providing less intuition.

Comment: If you look carefully the second solution, you will find that I use only mathematical analyis techniques and not arithmetic as the first solution( for information, I use $\frac{\pi}{k^2}$ just for reason of simplicity, but I can use any irrational value less than this term). Hence, it's completely a new method, not a variation.

Comment: By "slight variation", I meant your second proof shows that the conclusion of the "key lemma" holds without reduction mod 1 so long as y is sufficiently small. (This is easy to get from the base k argument too.) I suppose how "new" different arguments are is a matter of opinion, though logarithms are close enough to base k expansions that I personally don't consider the arguments particularly different. (That's not to say I dislike it!)

Answer (score 5):

**First solution of the problem**

We prove that for each $x \in(0,\pi)$, there exists $n,y\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\pi y + \frac{\pi}{k^2} \le x k^n\le \pi y +\pi - \frac{\pi}{k^2} \iff y +\frac{1}{k^2}\le  k^n\frac{x}{\pi} \le y+1-\frac{1}{k^2} \tag{1}$$
because $$(1) \iff |\sin(xk^n)| \ge \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{k^2} \right)$$

We write $\frac{x}{\pi}$ in [base-k numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) (aka: radix system)
as follows
$$\frac{x}{\pi} =\overline{0,s_1s_2s_3...s_n...}^{(\mathbf{k})} = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\frac{s_i}{k^i}=\frac{s_1}{k}+\frac{s_2}{k^2}+\frac{s_3}{k^3}+...+\frac{s_n}{k^n}+...$$
and then
$$k^n\frac{x}{\pi} =\overline{s_1s_2s_3...s_n,s_{n+1}s_{n+2}...}^{(\mathbf{k})}$$
The integer part $\left[k^n\frac{x}{\pi}\right]$ and the fractional part $\{k^n\frac{x}{\pi}\}$ of $k^n\frac{x}{\pi}$ are defined as
$$a_n =\left[k^n\frac{x}{\pi}\right] = \overline{s_1s_2s_3...s_n}^{(\mathbf{k})}$$
$$\epsilon_n=\left\{k^n\frac{x}{\pi}\right\} = \overline{0,s_{n+1}s_{n+2}...}^{(\mathbf{k})}$$

We notice that $0 \le \epsilon_n < 1$ and $k^n\frac{x}{\pi} = a_n + \epsilon_n $.

**Case 1:** $\frac{x}{\pi}$ is a [terminating decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Every_rational_number_is_either_a_terminating_or_repeating_decimal) in the base-k. Suppose $\frac{x}{\pi}$ has $N$ numbers after the $0$. Then, $\frac{x}{\pi}$ can be written as

$$\frac{x}{\pi} =\overline{0,s_1s_2s_3...s_N}^{(\mathbf{k})} = \frac{s_1}{k}+\frac{s_2}{k^2}+\frac{s_3}{k^3}+...+\frac{s_N}{k^N}$$
with $ 1 \le s_N \le (k-1)$.

Choose $y = a_{N-1}$ then $\epsilon_{N-1} = \overline{0,s_N}^{(\mathbf{k})} = \frac{s_N}{k}$. We can verify easily that $(y,n) = (a_{N-1},N-1)$ satisfy (1). Indeed, we have

$$a_{N-1}+\frac{1}{k^2} \le a_{N-1}+\frac{1}{k} \le  a_{N-1}+ \frac{s_{N-1}}{k} = a_{N-1}+ \epsilon_{N-1} = k^{N-1} \frac{x}{\pi}$$
and
$$k^{N-1} \frac{x}{\pi} = a_{N-1}+ \epsilon_{N-1} = a_{N-1}+ \frac{s_{N-1}}{k} \le a_{N-1}+ \frac{k-1}{k} \le a_{N-1}+ 1- \frac{1}{k^2}$$

**Case 2-a:** *$\frac{x}{\pi}$ is a non-terminating decimal (aka repeating decimal) in the base-k and there exists an $n$ such that $1 \le s_{n+1} \le (k-2)$.*

Then, $\epsilon_n = \overline{0,s_{n+1}s_{n+2}...}^{(\mathbf{k})}$ satisfies $\frac{1}{k} \le \epsilon_n \le \frac{k-1}{k}$. Choose $y=a_n$, we have

$$a_n +\frac{1}{k} \le  k^n\frac{x}{k\pi} \le a_n +\frac{k-1}{k} $$
$$\iff a_n +\frac{1}{k} \le  a_n+ \epsilon_n \le a_n +\frac{k-1}{k} \tag{2}$$

From (2), we can deduce that (1) holds true. Indeed, we have

$$a_n+\frac{1}{k^2 } \le a_n+\frac{1}{k} $$
and
$$a_N+ \frac{k-1}{k} \le a_N+ 1- \frac{1}{k^2}$$

**Case 2-b:**  *$\frac{x}{\pi}$ is a non-terminating decimal (aka repeating decimal) in the base-k and there doesn't exist an $n$ such that $1 \le s_{n+1} \le (k-2)$.*

So for all $i=1,...,+\infty$ we have $s_i = 0$ or $s_i=(k-1)$

Let $u$ is the first value such that $s_u = 0$ (if $u$ doesn't existe, then $s_u = (k-1)$ for all $u$. As we suppose $\frac{x}{\pi}$ is a non-terminating decimal, we have $\frac{x}{\pi} =\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(k-1)}{k^i} \rightarrow 1$ which is a contradiction.).

Let $v$ is the first value such that $v>u$ and $s_v = (k-1)$. (If $v$ doesn't existe, then $s_v = 0$ for all $v>u$. Then  $\frac{x}{\pi}$ is *not* a non-terminating decimal $\implies$ contradiction).
Hence, $\frac{x}{\pi}$ can be written as

$$\frac{x}{\pi} = \overline{0,s_{1}s_{2}...s_{u-1}00...00(k-1)s_{v+1}....}^{(\mathbf{k})}$$
In particular,
$$k^{v-1}\frac{x}{\pi} = \overline{..s_{v-2},0(k-1)s_{v+1}..}^{(\mathbf{k})}$$

Let's $y = a_{v-1}$ and $n = v-1$, we have
$$k^n\frac{x}{\pi} = a_{v-1} +  \overline{0,0(k-1)s_{v+1}..}^{(\mathbf{k})}$$
and
$$\overline{0,0(k-1)s_{v+1}..}^{(\mathbf{k})} = \frac{k-1}{k^2} + ... \in \left( 
 \frac{1}{k^2}, 1-\frac{1}{k^2} \right)$$
$$\implies a_n + \frac{1}{k^2} \le k^n\frac{x}{\pi} \le a_n + 1-\frac{1}{k^2}$$
So, (1) holds true.

**Conclusion**
Hence, we have for all $x\in (0,\pi), \exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\sin(xk^n)|\ge \sin(\frac{\pi}{k^2})$.

***Note:*** We can prove $ \forall x \in ]0,\pi[, \exists n \in \Bbb N, |\cos(xk^n)|\ge \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{k} \right)$ by using the same method. In fact, for the $|\cos(xk^n)|$, the proof is less difficult, it suffices to prove there exists $y,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $y \le  k^n\frac{x}{\pi} \le y+1-\frac{1}{k}$.

Hence, we have that $\forall x \in ]0,\pi[, \exists n,m \in \Bbb N$ such that $$|\sin(xk^n)|\ge \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{k^2} \right)$$
$$|\sin(xk^m)|\le \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{k} \right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Not a proof of the statement but close. 
Also, one should notice that the statement does not hold water for numbers in the form
$x=\frac{\pi*m}{k}$ where $m <=k$
The question remains if these are the only "bad" x's.
For the proof,
let $k_n$ be an increasing sequence of integers and $\sigma < \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.
Let $E = \{x; \overline {\lim}_{n \to \infty} |\sin(k_{n}x)| < \sigma \}$.
Lastly, let $\chi_{E}$ be characteristic function of $E$.

Then $m(E)=0$.

To see this, note that on one hand
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\chi_{E} \cos(2k_{n}x) dx$$ tends to $0$ because this is just a Fourier coefficient of integrable function.
At the same time since $\cos(2k_{n}x) = \frac { 1-2\sin^{2}k_nx}{2}$ one gets:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\chi_{E} \cos(2k_{n}x) dx = \frac{1}{2}m(E) - \int_{0}^{2\pi}\chi_{E} \sin^{2}(k_{n}x)dx $$, so regrouping and taking upper limits:
$$\frac{1}{2}m(E) <= \overline {\lim}_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\chi_{E} \cos(2k_{n}x) dx + \overline {\lim}_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\chi_{E} \sin^{2}(k_{n}x) dx $$
As remarked above the first term tends to $0$. 
The second one can be estimated by passing with upper limit inside the integral (Fatou's Lemma) and using definition of $E$, to get $<= \sigma^{2}m(E)$.

//////////////////////

This comment relates to the reformulated version of the problem added by Michelle on 2/15/2021.
The new statement suggest much simpler solution.
One looks at unit vectors (complex numbers) on the unit circle and the angle between them.
If two vectors have angle between them (mod $2\pi$) , say $\alpha$, which is less then $\frac{\pi}{k}$ then their image under $f$ maps this angle into $k*\alpha$ (mod $2\pi$). Hence, for any two vectors $z_1, z_2$ if $z_1 != z_2$ there is an $n$ such that the angle between $z_1^n$ and $z_2^n$ is at least $\frac{\pi}{k}$. This gives proper estimates on $\sigma$ that is $\sigma >= |1-e^{i*\frac{\pi}{4}}|$

Comment: What's wrong with $x=\pi m/k$? Note that $0\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: I guess your comment refers to an example on the top of my post. That is to the version of the problem with $|sin(x*k^n)| >= \sigma$. Well for $x=\frac{\pi *m}{k}$ , we have $sin(x*k^n) = 0$ unless $n=0$. If you claim that $0$ is a natural number then not only the problem trivializes but you are in totally different universe.

Comment: In my universe, $0$ is a natural number. And I don't really see how it's totally different than yours, nor how it trivializes the problem. But maybe you should ask the OP first: there are two conventions out there, one is $0\in\Bbb N$, the other $0\notin\Bbb N$, the former being the standard at least in France.

Comment: OK, I take back the part about different universe. But regarding the problem if we allow n=0. In such case the problem reduces to "small" $x$. And it is relatively easy to see that if $x <\frac{\pi}{k^{2}}$ modulo $2\pi$  then the next term is just multiplication by $k$. In words either $x >\frac{\pi}{k^{2}}$ or if not then it gets multiplied by $k$ so eventually it gets bugger then $\frac{\pi}{k^{2}} $.

Comment: By the way, I didn't pay great attention, but the OP is french and explicitly stated that $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2\dots\}$, so this question is settled.

Answer (score 2):

**Second solution of the problem**

We prove by absurdity. Suppose
$$\not\exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in ]0,\pi[, \exists n \in \Bbb N, |\sin(xk^n)|\ge \delta \tag{1}$$

We have $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$\forall\delta>0, \exists x \in ]0,\pi[, \forall n\in \Bbb N, |\sin(xk^n)|< \delta \tag{2}$$

Construct a sequence $\delta_p$ such that $\delta_p \xrightarrow{p\rightarrow+\infty}0$. Then there exists a sequence $x_p \in ]0,\pi[$ such that
$$\forall n\in \Bbb N, |\sin(x_pk^n)|< \delta_p$$

Take $n=0$, we have $|\sin(x_p)| \xrightarrow{p\rightarrow+\infty}0$. Because the function $|\sin(x)|$ continue and have only 2 roots in $[0,\pi]$, the sequence $x_p$ must then converge to the set of two values $\{\{0\},\{\pi\} \}$ (we remind that $0<x_p<\pi$ for all $p$). We can extract from the sequence $\{x_p \}$ a sub sequence $\{x_q \}$ such that  $x_q \xrightarrow{q\rightarrow+\infty} r \in \{\{0\},\{\pi\} \}$. Without loss of generality, we suppose $r=0$.

As $\delta_q \xrightarrow{q\rightarrow+\infty}0$ and $x_q \xrightarrow{q\rightarrow+\infty} 0$, , we can choose an $q$ such that
$$\delta_q < \sin(\frac{\pi}{k^2})$$ and $$x_q<\frac{\pi}{k^2} \tag{3}$$

From $(2)$, we have
$$\forall n\in \Bbb N, |\sin(x_qk^n)|< \delta_q < \sin(\frac{\pi}{k^2}) \tag{4}$$
We will prove that (4) can't hold true by seeking an $n$ such that
\begin{align}
(5):\frac{1}{k^2}\pi<x_qk^n<\frac{k^2-1}{k^2}\pi &\iff \ln(\frac{1}{k^2}\pi)<\ln(x_q)+n\ln(k)<\ln(\frac{k^2-1}{k^2}\pi) \\
&\iff \frac{\ln(\frac{1}{k^2})}{\ln(k)}<\frac{\ln(\frac{x_q}{\pi})}{\ln(k)}+n<\frac{\ln(\frac{k^2-1}{k^2})}{\ln(k)} \\
&\iff \frac{\ln(\frac{1}{k^2})}{\ln(k)}-\frac{\ln(\frac{x_q}{\pi})}{\ln(k)}<n<\frac{\ln(\frac{k^2-1}{k^2})}{\ln(k)} -\frac{\ln(\frac{x_q}{\pi})}{\ln(k)}\\
\end{align}

This interval has the length of $\frac{\ln(\frac{k^2-1}{k^2})-\ln(\frac{1}{k^2})}{\ln(k)} = \frac{\ln(k^2-1)}{\ln(k)} >1$. Besides, from (3), the left term $\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{k^2})}{\ln(k)}-\frac{\ln(\frac{x_q}{\pi})}{\ln(k)}$ is always postive. Then, there always exists $n_0 \in \Bbb N^*$ satisfying (5).

And we notice that, from (5), we have $$|\sin(x_0k^{n_0})|>\sin(\frac{\pi}{k^2}) \tag{6}$$

From (4) and (6), we have a contradiction. Hence, (1) can't hold true. Consequently, we can conclude that
$$\exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in ]0,\pi[, \exists n \in \Bbb N, |\sin(xk^n)|\ge \delta$$

Comment: $\frac{\ln(\frac{k^2-1}{k^2})-\ln(\frac{1}{k^2})}{\ln(k)} = \frac{\ln(k^2-1)}{\ln(k)} >k-1$ isn't true for $k =4$ for example, but $\frac{\ln(\frac{k^2-1}{k^2})-\ln(\frac{1}{k^2})}{\ln(k)} = \frac{\ln(k^2-1)}{\ln(k)} >1$ is true for $k\ge 2$ :)

Comment: I edit the comment. I remove $>k-1$ (it's unnecessary) and modifie to $ > 1$ and it's true for all $k \ge 2$.

Comment: Yes yes, see my (edited) comment